# perform knn with clustered input data

Tags: r, k-means, knn

How do I perform knn cross validation with input data that has been clustered using k-means.

I seem to be unable to find the correct function which is able to do so.

`predict.strengt` from `fpcseem` to be able to compute some form of prediction rate given a classifier method, but it seems it test it against the training set, which in my mind doesn't seem that beneficial.

Aren't there any function which can perform cross validation?

Example:

```
library("datasets")
library("stats")

iris_c3 = kmeans(iris$Sepal.Length,center= 10, iter.max = 30)
```

How do I provide `iris_c3` as training data for some form of `knn` which also performs cv, if a given test set was provided in the same manner.

Comment: See the `caret` package.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific..  functions in the caret library does perform crosvalidation but not with preprocessed data such kmeans.

Comment: I rather think you're the one who needs to be more specific. [There are a lot of clustering methods and utilities in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html). Sharing a small, reproducible example of what you have and more explicitly describing what you want would go a long way.

Comment: I've added a small example. I want see if how the determined number of cluster affect the knn classifier.   How well am i predicting with the number of clusters i have chosen?

At end i would like to have an confusion matrix as well..